# Copy spreadsheet lines values with filters on

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2016

Good Morning,

I have a spreadsheet, with filters.
So when I put filters, the spreadsheet change. But If I want to copy the result of the spreadsheet with filters on. How I need to do ?

This is my spreadsheet :

[image: Spreasheet]

This is my spreadsheet with filter "Paris":

[image: Spreadsheet with filter]

And I want this result in another range like this :

[image: Exemple excpected]

The problem is how to link the result ? So the new range get the spreasheet values ?

- I tried to Simply copy but of course it doesn't work.
- I tried to link with the cell value (for exemple I put =K14, =K15...)
- I tried to link with the spreasheet value (for exemple =Spreadsheet1[@[colonne 3]]) but it doesn't refesh

Have you another idea ?

Comment: Copying a filtered table will give you the result you seem to be looking for. Are you looking for an approach that will always match your filtered selection (e.g. the result will show Paris if that is selcted or NYC is that is selected)?

Comment: Yes exactly ! I am looking for a dynamic copy

Comment: Are you looking to copy by hand, or to have a direct link between both?

Comment: Direct link, so if I change the filter in the spreadsheet, the new range change too

Comment: To link the result of a filtered table try a `FormulaArray`

Comment: It doen't work. It copy the cells who is not showed too...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe can I try with VBA ?
I wan to copy only the visible cells